# NVR Viewer for Ubuntu

Tags: security, camera, rtsp

I've looked around and maybe I'm not searching correctly; or no one has this specific setup. I have a Sannce DT41DC1T security camera NVR. Analog cameras plug directly into the unit. Instead of viewing the camera feed directly from the NVR with a monitor I've been using software titled simple CMS on Windows to connect to the NVR and view the cameras on multiple systems. I'd like to try and break away from Windows on this one and use my Ubuntu boxes. I sort of have ZoneMinder set up, and the cameras sort of work. Some cameras will pull up with RTSP on ZoneMinder temporarily, and then go black. Maybe I'm doing something wrong there. Is there any known easy solution like CMS for Ubuntu, or anyone with expertise in attempting this sort of setup?

Comment: You could try your RTSP feeds in VLC media player (Open Network Stream) that may at least let you know if the problem is Zoneminder or your cameras RTSP feed. There is `CCTV Viewer` in the Ubuntu store/snap store but I have not tried it. For me CCTV is now the ONLY reason I keep a Windows PC around as manufacturers only seem to support Windows & Mac for software :-(

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the exact same RTSP urls with Shinobi (I put it on an ubuntu server/raspberry pi I had laying around), and it works PERFECTLY. Minimal setup, and works ALMOST as fast as the CMS software on Windows but with 3x more functionality. After getting this working I'd recommend Shinobi for such things. For anyone in the future looking for an answer to this specific NVR the RTSP URL that worked is:
rtsp://192.168.0.x:554/user=username&password=password&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100

I have 4 cameras connected to that NVR so simply clone another input, channel=2, channel=3, etc.

[Shinobi working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic95u.jpg)